# C# - WPF - Bind Style.Setters

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have spent all day looking for a way to to bind property in Row Style Setters from DataGrid and the bind fails

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
  <Style.Setters>
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
  </Style.Setters>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I tried custom converters
And it did not work, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient context.  For example: what message is provided about the binding not working?  Has the DataContext been properly set?  You need to provide a sufficient amount of code to help.

Comment: You went right from tag `<DataGrid.RowStyle>` to tag `<Style.Setters>`.  You forgot the actual `<Style>` tag you need between them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure really what to do here. Since you haven't given me a lot to work with. So I will assume that everything else is setup correctly and you are missing the style.

I remember that you might have to specify what to target in your style. In this case "DataGridRow".
So you need a `<Style TargetType="DataGridRow">` tag before the Style Setter

```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding MyProperty}"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```